Regular expression for binary numbers
I need to find regular expression for strings representing binary numbers that are not less than 51.
How can I do that? I can't find any pattern in their binary pepresentation.

Just look at the patterns for numbers that are less than 8 and do the same for 51

@jimjim i can't see any either...

You can split the range $[0,51]$ into several shorter intervals that can each be matched by some pattern. In particular, $[48,51]$ is one simple pattern, $[32,47]$ another.
